# Is Worth To Use MD5 If I Just Want To Get A Friendly Identify Of String

Tags: java, md5, uniqueidentifier

I have some objects and I want to group them use some fields. My solution is sort those fields by name. Then joint them to Key1=Value1&Key2=Value2... At first, I think to use the hash code of that Key-Value pair string. But different JDK will may generate different hash code algorithm. I need to keep following object can go into their group like previous. So I need a consistent identify algorithm.

I want to use MD5. But I didn't need any encrypt function here. All I need just turn "tn=site&ie=utf-8" like string in to a friendly group ID. Is there another way to resolve this?

Comment: Use MD5. There could be collisions. What part doesn't work?

Comment: md5 sounds like a good option.

Comment: You could also serialize the Strings and use Base64 on it.

Comment: Does it matter if string is unique or not?

Comment: string is fine to indentify,but I need a friendly group id to show to others didn't know the details of these objects.

Comment: Base64 is 3 times long than the source string. It's horrible if I have very long source string.

Comment: It better if I could figure out a method to generate group id base on exist group.